# IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files - but I close all files

Tags: python, file, loops, io, ioerror

I am reading every 0.01s a file, but I does it with

```
with open('file.txt','r') as FILE:
    data = FILE.read()
```

Which should be according to official documentation save way to open and close file.

In the same time I write into the same file once in a while(2s-20s) in a same fashion but with 'w' flag - but from totally different python process

After like 20minutes of proper working I get this error

```
IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files:
```

I think it is totally ridiculous error. One interesting thing happened which I feel obliged to mention here. As this is going on in my raspberry pi and there was no reason to expect this error I didnt cover errors with LOG. So i tried to log the error and something strange happened:

```
while True:
    ...
    #loop where I read every 0.01 a file, IOError of the reading file happens
    ...
    except Exception as e: # log the IOEerror
        with open('log_error.txt','w') as FILE: # Cacthes the error but triggers a new IOError
            FILE.write(e)
```

After IOError occured, new error occured in Exception and instead of IOError of reading file, I got the IOError for logging the error in log_error.txt

Anyone knows what is going on? I cant really figure it out as it crashes after 20min to 2h (that means minimally file was opened atleast 20*60/0.01 and no error occurs). It simply works until it doesnt. Thanks for any advice

**EDIT - Code:**
I have MQTT subscriber that receives commands (writing in file on path:`self.path_anim_current`)

```
if payload['request']=='write_in':
    with open(self.path_anim_current,'w') as FILE:
        FILE.write(payload['data'])
```

In different process I try to catch the change in file as quickly as possible - thats the 0.01s reading loop, where I read the file on `self.path_anim_current`

This is extract of the 0.01s reading loop:
`PATH` = `self.path_anim_current`

```
with open(PATH,'r') as FILE:
        ANIMATION = FILE.read()
if ANIMATION != '':
    COMMAND = rc.process_json(str(ANIMATION))
    with open(PATH,'w') as FILE:
        FILE.write('') #**On reading the file I want to delete its content**
```

rc.process_json - its just a function that loads json file with some config

reading json is in standard way

```
with open('path_to_some_config') as FILE:
        DOCUMENT = json.load(FILE)
```

Comment: sure the issue comes from this file handle ? could you show how you're writing the files?

Comment: I added code to all manipulation with the file from different processes

Comment: are you sure there aren't other file open operations somewhere else in your code?

Comment: There are more file operations, but they are json oriented and only reading mode and they are operating in imported module. I open it and close it immedieatly. Also there is no such huge timefrequency. Except 0.01s loop everything else is in timeframe from 1-3s up and everything is loaded very fast

Comment: To be honest, there is one more strange thing that happened, but I didnt want to include it because its hard to explain, but since you try to inquire more in the problem... I have 7 lamps that all have particualr led animations. All lamps can receive and send commands and play led animations. Yesterday 1 lamp was sending to itself and to 6 others commands(processed as mentioned above). And in the same time 1. lamp send comand to 2.,2. on receive send command to 3.rd and so on until 7th send command to 1. and again.The IOError was happening on those lamps in the given order. but that is nonsens

Comment: So there were 2 animation loops going on. Loop1: 1th Lamp was sending to all, and Loop2: 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-1. At some point IOError happened on 3rd. So i restarted and it happened after a while on 4th. and so on in order. But thats nonsense, because if one lamp broke and destroyed the chain Loop2, there was still going on Loop1 and 6 devices kept receiving messages(opening files and so on.). By this example I want to just demonstrate that its unlikely that IOError happened because of some opening files accumulation over time